# How do I detect particular peaks that last more than one time step using scipy.find_peaks?

Tags: python, scipy

I have a time series where I'm using find_peaks to detect spikes. Right now, I have the following code to detect spikes, which is working well.

```
find_peaks(x, threshold = 15)
```

However, I've noticed it's not detecting spikes that last more than one time step, as shown below. Is there a parameter that can assist with that?
[image]

Edit:

There are 16 data points in the above image with the values as follows: [50.7 50.6 50.6  7.6 12.  50.6 50.4 50.4 50.4 50.4 50.3 50.3 50.2 50.2
50.2 50.2]

Comment: What the sampling rate of your data? i.e. how many datapoints do you have in the above plots? Can you please paste the values somewhere where we can have access to them?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for this function? The last example in its docstring seems to demonstrate what you're trying to do

Comment: Paul, if I'm not mistaken, the width parameter sets the minimum width for a spike to be flagged. The default is none, so without specifying it, the spike should be flagged (in theory). I've looked at the documentation but frankly the parameter descriptions are not clear to me

Comment: Also worth noting I am trying to get the package to flag spikes that last 2 time steps as shown in the image, as well as 1 time step such as: [26.7 26.7  1.4 26.8 26.8]

Comment: Your data is very grainy. In your case, the find_peaks is detecting the first peak but neglecting the second one, since the difference between those two peaks does not register as a peak. I would rather go with a much better approach, such as with z-score peak transformation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data

Comment: Peaks which last more than one sample can be detected by using prominence rather than threshold. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786670/what-is-the-difference-between-threshold-and-prominence-in-scipy-find-peaks/